# Jabber on ubuntu-touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, xmpp, jabber

I don't see any jabber or xmpp app in the ubuntu store.
Is there any for ubuntu-touch? Would it be possible that I don't see all there is in the store?
Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

As yet I have not seen any Jabber paps in the app store. You could use the internet site to search, if you search uäpp you will find it. If not there is a wish list section you could add to.. This may prompt some development in it or if work is already going on, you may get an update.

Comment: I have done this in the past with apps that i want but are not available. Hopefully this will help the app store grow to rival the other main players. I personally feel gamws are a good way to go, to get more younger people and gamera into Touch.